# insert "Finally" to complete the code

Tags: java

i hav written a program in java using both get and set method....but it does not give me the desired output it tells insert finally block my code is given below..in the console  of eclipse it shows only  connected but no values of table displayed

```
      package com.glomindz.mercuri.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.glomindz.mercuri.pojo.User;
import com.glomindz.mercuri.util.MySingleTon;

  public class UserServicesDAO {

private Connection connection;

public UserServicesDAO() {
    // connection = new MySingleTon().getConnection();
    connection = MySingleTon.getInstance().getConnection();

}

public List<User> get_all_data() {
    List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM spl_user_master";
    try {
         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
         boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
            user.setMobile(resultSet.getString("mobile"));
            user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
            user.setRole(resultSet.getString("role"));
            user.setStatus(resultSet.getString("status"));
            user.setLast_udpate(resultSet.getString("last_update"));
            usersList.add(user);
        }
    }
    } 

    public List<User> set_all_data() {
        List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
        try {
             PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO spl_user_master(name,email,mobile,password,role,status,last_update)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
             stmt.setString(1, "Charlie Sheen");
             stmt.setString(2, "help@glomindz.com");
             stmt.setString(3, "9554087107");
             stmt.setString(4, "cbf91a71c21d5ec348b0c749b2f0055k");
             stmt.setString(5, "user");
             stmt.setString(6, "3");
             stmt.setString(7, "2013-07-02 22:05:16");


             boolean execute = stmt.execute();
            System.out.println(execute);
            stmt.getResultSet();

        } 

        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return usersList;
        }


       public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserServicesDAO userdao = new UserServicesDAO();
    List<User> data = userdao.get_all_data();
    List<User> data1 = userdao.set_all_data();
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(data1);
    System.exit(0);
                }
                   }
```

whats wrong with the code plz specify

Comment: You can't have an isolated `try`: it must be followed by a `catch`, a `finally` or both.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `try{` clause in `get_all_data` ?

Comment: your first try needs an associated finally or catch block

Comment: try should be followed by catch of finally compulsorily

Answer (score 4):

In java, `try` block must be followed either by a `catch` or a `finally` block. In your code you have the below try block, which is not followed by a catch/finally block(s).

```
  try {
         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
         boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
            user.setMobile(resultSet.getString("mobile"));
            user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
            user.setRole(resultSet.getString("role"));
            user.setStatus(resultSet.getString("status"));
            user.setLast_udpate(resultSet.getString("last_update"));
            usersList.add(user);
        }
    } // missing catch/finally statements
```

You can either add a catch block to handle any exception happening in the above try block code or put a finally block. The general construct for a try block is

```
try {
    code
}
catch and finally blocks . . .
```

Learn more about java exception handling here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: its working  in the database table it is updated but  in my console of eclipse it shows output   
true
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData@117e889
false
and the previous data but not the updated table with new values why plz answer me

Answer (score 1):

You can not have only try{ } in Java. try { } block must be followed by either catch{ } or finally{ }.

So here you should use either `catch{ }` or `finnaly{ }` for code utilization.

```
try{
....
....
}finally{
//cleanup
}

try{
....
....
}catch(Exception e)
{
....
....
}
```

You can also refer this :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Answer (score 1):

You need a catch block if you want to catch exceptions.

```
try {
....
} catch (Exception e) {
....
}
```

If you use try and finally combination, note that try is there *only* to allow *finally*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign  stmt.getResultSet(); to anything! UserList is an empty list as nothing is added to it. You need to add the results of  stmt.getResultSet(); to the list.

For finally: The code block in finally will be executed for sure - but it is **NOT** sure when! Use finally to close database connections or other clean up work. Or better, do not use it at all. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec7

Use a catch block to catch errors

Comment: how to add plzz specify me by writing the code

Comment: See Juned Ahsan's post for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a try block only. To have a try block you must have at least one catch block or a finally block